# How to Fix: Show Sub-Category on Category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I'm having issues with my coding, I'm trying to show my category's sub-categories thumbnails on the category page in all categoies.

The problem is that it's showing the same sub-category on different categories instead of just showing it into only its parent category.

**CMS Block:**

```
{{block type="core/template" template="subcategories.phtml" }}
```

**.PHTML File:**

```
<div class="clearfix title-container product-slider-container"></div>
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>"/></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[This his my website where I have it set up, navigate to one of the categories in the Header menu.](http://premiumautodynamics.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento caches your current category. You have to options.

Remove static block and call it through xml layout update in the category. Inside the block call

```
<reference name="needed block"> <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action> </reference>
```

Or

Get current category via

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams()
```

**Edit**:

In backend go to manage categories 
Remove static block. 
Go to layout update and put

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="my_block" template="subcategories.phtml" before="-">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>
</block></reference>
```

Also you may want to rename the variable `$category` in .phtml when you are inside the loop. You don't want any time your theme calls `$category` from that line of code and after to be a child category.

Comment: How do I set the that up?

Comment: Can anyone help me set this up?

Comment: I need help, can anyone help

Comment: Did you try the reference method?

Comment: I didn't see your edit, it works like charm, just what I was looking for. But I have an issue, how can I hide the Category title showing below the thumbnails, as well as the breadcrumbs, I have the breadcrumbs disabled on the settings, but still show up. I attached an IMGUR http://i.imgur.com/am0PKD3.png

Comment: for that you have to edit your `app/design/frontned/your/theme/catalog/product/category/view.phtml` and remove the h1 title or put an if statement for that category. Alternatively you can try instead of `before="-"` type `before="category.products"` to see if this pushes your block after the headline. If you want to remove breadcrumbs completely edit your theme's local.xml and put `<reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>`

Comment: I have edited the view.phtml and it doesn't do any changes to the website even clearing caches. This is what I commented out and even deleted it, but still doesn't do anything to the front end. `if ($_category) {
    echo '<div class="product-category-title"><h3>' . $_category->getName() . '</h3></div>';
   }`

Comment: I can't manage to hide the page/category <h1> title

Answer (score 0):

Add below given code into your **cms blocks** design section

```
<reference name="content">
         <block type="core/template" name="my_block" template="subcategories.phtml" before="-">
             <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>
         </block>
</reference>
```